# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, can't find solution to error

Tags: javascript, datetime, calculator

This is what JS tells me whenever I calculate a date that is in the past:
[image]

I tried different ways to format the pop-up but always got the same error. Tried to use:

```
      y = Math.abs(diffDays);
      alert("That was exactly " (y) + " in the past!");

      alert("That was exactly " Math.abs(diffDays) + " in the past!");

      alert("That was exactly " (Math.abs(diffDays)) + " in the past!");
```

All those failed. I know it should be something simple, I just can't figure it out. Can someone please explain what is wrong in the code? Here it is:

```
function Calculator(){

  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  var y = document.getElementById("year").value;
  var yy = document.getElementById("month").value;
  var yyy = document.getElementById("day").value;
  const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var oneDate = new Date(y, yy - 1, yyy);
  var diffDays = Math.round((oneDate - today) / oneDay);
  if (oneDate.getFullYear() == y && oneDate.getMonth() == (yy-1) && oneDate.getDate() == yyy) {
    if (diffDays == 0)
    {
      alert("That is today you dumby dumb :3")
    } else if (diffDays < 0 ) {
      y = Math.abs(diffDays);
      alert("That was exactly " y + " in the past!");
    } else {
      alert("That date will be in exactly " + (diffDays) + " days!");
    }
  } else {
      alert('Invalid date!!!');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a concatenator (in several of your alerts).

```
alert("That was exactly " + Math.abs(diffDays) + " in the past!");
                          ^
                          ^
                          ^
```